# How to check which fallback handler is set for a Gnosis Safe

Tags: gnosis-safe, fallback-function

I am using a 1.3 Gnosis Safe.
I want to check what fallback handler is set.
I find the function that can set it:

```
function internalSetFallbackHandler(address handler) internal {
    bytes32 slot = FALLBACK_HANDLER_STORAGE_SLOT;
    // solhint-disable-next-line no-inline-assembly
    assembly {
        sstore(slot, handler)
    }
}
```

But as it is not using a regular solidity variable that automatically generates a getter function but instead writes it via assembly directly into storage I don't know an easy way how to read it for a given Safe?

Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

You can read it with the "getStorageAt" function at this storage address (derived from the keccak hash of "fallback_manager.handler.address"): `0x6c9a6c4a39284e37ed1cf53d337577d14212a4870fb976a4366c693b939918d5`
converted to a decimal number it is: `49122629484629529244014240937346711770925847994644146912111677022347558721749`

So finally you should get this:
[image]